# row_number / dense_rank (Group & Island)

Tags: sql, sql-server, row-number, gaps-and-islands, dense-rank

Below you will find test data to play with. What I need is a dense_rank, rank, row_number whatever function to get the rows numbered as in "NoRequired".
I tested every rank and row_number function and even tried to use WITH statements, but didn't come up with a solution yet.

I guess the main problem here is, that the "rank function" needs to skip a sequence once there is a different key value in between...

```
DECLARE @data TABLE (ID int IDENTITY(1,1), X int, NoRequired int);

INSERT INTO @data(X, NoRequired)
    VALUES (1000,1), (1000,1), (800,2), (600,3), (1000,4), (1000,4), (800,5);

SELECT *
FROM @data;
```

Comment: You may be interested in [*this answer to, "Solving “Gaps and Islands” with row_number() and dense_rank()?*](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/167069/2639)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a "group and islands" problem.  One simple method is to use lag and a cumulative sum:

```
select d.*,
       sum(case when prev_x = x then 0 else 1 end) over (order by id) as NoRequired
from (select d.*, lag(x) over (order by id) as prev_x
      from @data d
     ) d;
```

The idea is to identify rows where the value changes and then do a cumulative sum of those values.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @data TABLE (ID int IDENTITY(1,1), X int, NoRequired int);

INSERT INTO @data(X, NoRequired)
    VALUES (1000,1), (1000,1), (800,2), (600,3), (1000,4), (1000,4), (800,5);

SELECT D.ID, D.X, D.NoRequired, MAX(RQ.RN) MyVal  FROM @DATA D JOIN 
            (SELECT D1.ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY D1.ID) RN FROM @data D1 
                LEFT JOIN @data D2
                    ON D1.ID = D2.Id + 1 
                    AND D1.X = D2.X
                        WHERE D2.Id IS NULL) RQ 
            ON RQ.ID <= D.ID
            GROUP BY D.ID, D.X, D.NoRequired 
            ORDER BY D.ID
```